# cataloginventory_stock_item - errno: 150 Foreign key constrain is incorrectly formed

Tags: magento2, database, import

I'm tranfering my magento2 website locally.

Importing website database gives me the following error:

**ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 636351: Can't create table 'cataloginventory_stock_item' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constrain is incorrectly formed")**

This is the sql part that causes this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
CREATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item` (
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Item Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `stock_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Stock Id',
  `qty` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Qty',
  `min_qty` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000 COMMENT 'Min Qty',
  `use_config_min_qty` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Use Config Min Qty',
  `is_qty_decimal` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Is Qty Decimal',
  `backorders` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Backorders',
  `use_config_backorders` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Use Config Backorders',
  `min_sale_qty` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.0000 COMMENT 'Min Sale Qty',
  `use_config_min_sale_qty` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Use Config Min Sale Qty',
  `max_sale_qty` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000 COMMENT 'Max Sale Qty',
  `use_config_max_sale_qty` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Use Config Max Sale Qty',
  `is_in_stock` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Is In Stock',
  `low_stock_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Low Stock Date',
  `notify_stock_qty` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Notify Stock Qty',
  `use_config_notify_stock_qty` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Use Config Notify Stock Qty',
  `manage_stock` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Manage Stock',
  `use_config_manage_stock` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Use Config Manage Stock',
  `stock_status_changed_auto` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Stock Status Changed Automatically',
  `use_config_qty_increments` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Use Config Qty Increments',
  `qty_increments` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000 COMMENT 'Qty Increments',
  `use_config_enable_qty_inc` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Use Config Enable Qty Increments',
  `enable_qty_increments` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Enable Qty Increments',
  `is_decimal_divided` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Is Divided into Multiple Boxes for Shipping',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Website ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID` (`product_id`,`stock_id`),
  KEY `CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  KEY `CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_STOCK_ID` (`stock_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_STOCK_ID_CATINV_STOCK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`stock_id`) REFERENCES `cataloginventory_stock` (`stock_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Cataloginventory Stock Item';
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Show your catalog_product_entity and cataloginventory_stock table sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the link below with the answer if it helps!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150

Also, try to disable foreign keys checks and import them again if it helps!

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ...
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```